# Can you use strongly typed / versioned powershell cmdlet parameters, or a C#-like using directive?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm working with the below type in powershell:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
```

I create objects, pass them around, return them from cmdlets etc. Here's an example:

```
Import-Module SQLPS

function New-SQLSMORelocateFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $logicalName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $physicalName
    )

    New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" `
     -ArgumentList $logicalName, $physicalName
}
```

I want to pass this value into another powershell cmdlet, as follows:

```
function Restore-SQLDatabaseFromDisk {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile] $overrideDataFile
    )

    # Do stuff
}
```

But when I do, I get the following helpful error:

> PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" value of type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Re locateFile" to type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile".
>         ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" value of type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer. Management.Smo.RelocateFile" to type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile".
>         ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'overrideDataFile'. Cannot
>   convert the "Micr osoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" value
>   of type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile" to type
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile".

I've seen this before; it's because the loaded "RelocateFile" version mismatches the one returned from my New-SQLSMORelocateFile() (which is required the SQLPS `Restore-SqlDatabase` cmdlet).

Whenever I use the "RelocateFile" type in my module, it *always* needs to be the "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" type, rather than the default loaded by SQLPS.

Is there a Powershell equivalent to C#'s "using" directive to override the behaviour of a type in a module, as demonstrated below?:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

As in the 3rd example: `using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;`

Alternatively, is there a way I can define a specific version of a parameter type, like this:

```
function Restore-SQLDatabaseFromDisk {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        ["Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"] $overrideDataFile
    )

    # Do stuff
}
```

The above obviously produces a syntax error, but I've not been able to come up with or find a way to do it.

Comment: My God, that worked! Could have swore I tried that, though I could have also wrapped it as a variable (DRY'n that). Thanks!

Comment: You can also do Add-Type?  There is nice read http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/add-type-vs-reflectionassembly-in.html

Comment: I've been playing around with Add-Type, but not had any success yet. I'll read that article, see if I get anywhere. Would still prefer to remove all the duplicate type declarations if possible.

Comment: @Spikeh Added a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

The type literal syntax allows fully qualified type names, just do:

```
param(
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]$MyParameter
)
```

Comment: Thanks, silly oversight on my behalf - though I'd still like to know if there's a using directive equivalent, or a way to alias the type (maybe via Add-Type) as I have quite a few cmdlets within my module that reference that type - maintenance nightmare.

Comment: There's a `using namespace` directive for use with the new classes feature in PowerShell 5.0, but I don't think it supports the use case you're interested in

Comment: Have any links or examples? All I need to do is essentially alias one class. The assembly is already loaded, so I don't think Add-Type will work here.

Comment: Found some. You're right, it doesn't do what I need - though it's VERY handy to know as I can use that to reduce some other types I've been working with, thank you.

Comment: @Spikeh [Check this simple example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32510.windows-management-framework-5-0-using-namespace-construct.aspx)